# Expandable View with scroll view in react native issue

Tags: react-native, scrollview, expandablelistview

I created nested expandable view and when scrolling up or down user click on a view to expand it than that touch doesn't respond but once scroll gets it position. User can click and it will respond to expand it. 
I can solved it by setting bounces property as false but i don't think it is a good way to handle this.

Comment: Could you share some code that reproduces the problem? (Preferably with https://snack.expo.io/ )?

Comment: Actually code is confidential so i can not share it

Comment: It doesn’t have to be your actual production code, just a minimal representative example so that we can reproduce the issue. Otherwise it’s difficult for anyone to help.